# ItemTouchHelper RecyclerView callback doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For some reason I can't get the swipe event from ItemTouchHelper. I am sure I am missing something but I don't know what. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
 final CarouselLayoutManager layoutManager = new CarouselLayoutManager(CarouselLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
            layoutManager.setPostLayoutListener(new CarouselZoomPostLayoutListener());


        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ConciergeCarouselAdapter(DemoData.getTopMenu()));
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new CenterScrollListener());


        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMove(final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                            final RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int swipeDir) {
                        Out.o(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()); 
                    }
                };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

**UPDATE**

I added these lines of code inside ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback :

```
@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
      return true;
}
```

If I place a breakpoint on the line "return true;" when I swipe the program stops, but when I place a breakpoint inside onSwiped nothing happens.

**UPDATE 2**

I replaced the CarouselLayoutManager with LinearLayoutManager and now I am able to catch the onSwiped event. Although I need to use CarouselLayoutManager.

Comment: Attach it to recyclerview before setting adapter.

Comment: Didn't work.. :/